# How to check if a message contains a channel mention (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So here is my code, I want to create a command through discord.py that writes a message with "say *[message]*" and writes a message in a channel with "say *[channel] [message]*". For the most part, I got it out. The problem I have is that I would like to check whether the first argument after the command "say" is a channel mention.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="_")  

@client.command(aliases=['echo', 'print'], description="say <message>")
    async def say(ctx, channel, *, message=""): 
        await ctx.message.delete()
    
        if not channel:
            await ctx.send("What do you want me to say?")
        else:
            if channel == discord.TextChannel.mention:
                await ctx.send("test")
            else:
                await ctx.send(str(channel) + " " + message)
```

I already tried using discord.textchannel, discord.message.channel_mentions and a few others, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use some of the fancy [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters)  features to have the command parsing machinery do this for us:

```
from typing import Optional
from discord import TextChannel

@client.command(aliases=['echo', 'print'], description="say <message>")
async def say(ctx, channel: Optional[TextChannel], *, message=""):
    channel = channel or ctx  # default to ctx if we couldn't detect a channel
    await channel.send(message)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```